# C++ How to compile WxWidget programs using MinGW?

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets

I'm using MinGW g++ and have installed and `-mingw32-make`'d the wxWidgets library files. But, when i try to compile a simple program:

```
// test.cpp
#include "wx/wx.h"

int main( int , char** )
{
     return 0;
};
```

The linking fails.

I use this command line

```
g++ test.cpp - o test.exe
```

It appears I need extra linker parameters. What exactly do I need?

Also, I was searching around a little bit, and I found someone saying i should use `-mingw32-make -n` on a sample program in the wxWidgets folder, and use the same parameters for my own file, but that fails as well.

This is what I get as an error message:

`g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -g -mthreads -L.....\lib\gcc_lib -Wl,--      subsystem,windows -mwindows    -lwxmsw31ud_core  -lwxbase31ud    -lwxtiffd -lwxjpegd -lwxpngd   -lwxzlibd -lwxregexud -lwxexpatd   -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lwininet
d:/programming/software/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxmsw31ud_core
d:/programming/software/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxbase31ud
d:/programming/software/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxtiffd
d:/programming/software/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxjpegd
d:/programming/software/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxpngd
d:/programming/software/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxzlibd
d:/programming/software/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxregexud
d:/programming/software/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxexpatd
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Is the error message a secret?

Comment: No, I edited the question to show it. Thanks for pointing out that I should include it.

Comment: `-L.....\lib\gcc_lib` What's this supposed to do? All those dots in a row?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea. I found it as a sample program parameter when I was inspecting the sample's makefile. I just copy and pasted it mindlessly. Should it not be here?

Comment: So you're just typing random things? Then why are you surprised nothing works? Programming by guessing doesn't work. Study, and understand.

Comment: Okay, don't be like that. I came here because I had no other resources - again, It seems I need some parameters, because linking fails, but I can't find the parameters anywhere. I followed advice from another question, and it didn't get me very far. So can you help me, or are you gonna bash on me for trying?

Comment: Which other question. It could help people without off-hand knowledge of the precise flags to piece it together you know.

Comment: Simply put, you'll have to know where these libraries are, and point the linker to it using the `-L` flag. You probably don't need the thing with `gcc_lib` (I guess, but I don't use MingW)

Comment: @EnnMichael, when you downloaded the library you have a complete source code as well as the documentation which resides in the interface and doc directories. Simply put you can start by compiling the library properly according to the documentation and then build the samples and then work with your own project.

Answer (score 0):

How to include lib directory and how to specify library name for linking?

```
 g++ test.cpp -L/path/to/library/directory -lwxpngd -o test.exe
```

What is ?  `-lwxpngd`
-l =  lib
`wxpngd` name of lib without prefix `lib`
`-lwxpngd`  =  `-libwxpngd`

And `-L/path/to/library/directory` is the path where libwxpngd is located.

Comment: Thanks. I actually managed to do it. You were right, I should've just read up about how to use MinGW first. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Ramy, this is not the way to work with wxWidgets. Please check the documentation at least prior to suggesting something.

Answer (score 0):

For better experience is recommended to use build tools like cmake or IDE like codeblocks. Since you are using mingw (which I assume is in a Win32 system) you need to create makefile pointing to two include files: one for the lib or dll config file (created when you compile wxWidgets), include directory of the wxWidgets framework and libraries to be used. I recommend to read this [page](http://wiki.esoftserve.com/tiki-index.php?page=WxWidgets) which sumarize the hole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a video on this topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6FDNR3lh8E
Here is small and simple steps to follow.

Pre-Requirements :

- GNU g++ compiler downloaded and installed.
- Set gcc/g++ path to Enviroment Variable.
- Download WxWidgets Binaries : 1. Header Files, 2. Development Files, 3. DLLs.
- Extract then one folder as it is. I have extracted them at D:\WxAPI Folder.
  Looks Like :
  D:
  - WxAPI Folder
  - include (Header files has this folder ziped in .7z)
  - lib (Development Files & DLL has this folder ziped in .7z and both extracts in this save folder)
- Set your project development structure.

  My Project Development Structure :

  ```
   WxExample (Project Folder)
       - Build (Folder) : Contains debug and release dlls and exe
           - debug (Folder) : Contains debug specific dlls and exe.
           - release (Folder) : Contains release specific dlls and exe.
       - inlcude (Folder) : Contains project header files.
       - src (Folder) : Contains project .cpp files.
       - wxCompiler.cmd : Contains compile command created with following steps.
  ```
- Write Compilation Command

  - Link Following to Compile.

  1. First Compile Project *.cpp Files :
     g++ ".\src*.cpp"
  2. Give Project Output .exe Name :
     -o ".\build\release\Project_Name.exe"
  3. Show Project .h File Location to g++ :
     -I ".\include"
  4. Provide WxWidget .h Files :
     -I "D:\WxAPI\include"
  5. Locate WxWidget setup.h File :
     -I "D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll\mswu"
  6. Supply Binaries Location of WxWidgets :
     -L "D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll"
  7. Provide Compile Flags :
     -l wxbase31u
     -l wxmsw31u_core

  - Here D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll\libwxbase31u.a File Renamed To "wxbase31u"
    & D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll\libwxmsw31u_core.a File Renamed To "wxmsw31u_core" as flag.
  - You have to add similar file flag as you used in your project as .h
  - For Example :
    -lwxmsw31u_core  -lwxbase31u    -lwxtiff -lwxjpeg -lwxpng   -lwxzlib -lwxregexu -lwxexpat   -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lwininet -loleacc -luxtheme
  - Here is Full Command :
    g++ ".\src*.cpp" -o ".\build\release" -I "D:\WxExample\include" -I "D:\WxAPI\include" -I "D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll\mswu" -L "D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll" -l wxbase31u -l wxmsw31u_core

- Run wxWidgets.cmd and that's it. Your exe is in your .\Build\release folder.

  8. Set WxWidget DLL path in Enviroment Variable.
     If you do not want to copy paste required dll to your release/debug folder.